# Is it possible to retrieve Cloud Page User's Time zone?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, cloudpage

I am trying to retrieve the time zone from a cloud page to populate and ICS file I am generating. The file is created fine, but the time is incorrect.

Is it retrieve to pass the user's time zone so I can make the adjustments?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use client-side javascript to get this information. I would recommend using the below snippet:

```javascript
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
```

This is supported in the majority of browsers, so should work for most needs. This info is taken from the Stack Overflow answer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-time-zone-and-offset-in-javascript#34602679)** so please reference it for more information if you need it.

Please note though, this is CLIENT-SIDE Javascript, not SERVER SIDE Javascript, meaning it will be processed after the server has returned the page to the browser.